# Partial views in ASP.NET MVC 3 (multi partial view into one view)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want views several partial view into a one view. 
In fact, it is like a master form that also includes several sub-forms.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could put this in a partial:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial1")
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Foo/Partial2")
@Html.Partial("Partial3")
```

and finally include this partial somewhere:

```
@Html.Partial("CombinedViewsPartial")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view, use this:

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfYourView")

@Html.Partial("../OtherViewFolder/NameOfPartialView", varToPassAsModel)
```

Or in a loop:

```
@foreach(var orderLine in model.OrderLines) {
   @Html.Partial("../OrderLine/Details", orderLine) @* Without executing another controller *@
   @Html.Action("Details", "OrderLine", new { lineNr = orderLine.LineNr, orderNr = orderLine.OrderNr }) @* Goes through controller *@
}
```

Comment: Hi Maryam, Please select the answer that helped you to solve your problem or at least explain how your problem was solved. By doing this you respect the person who helped you and also you help the other website users to learn more from your experience. Thanks